# Mootools Element.prototype error

Tags: javascript, mootools

I want to implement some functions and variables into Element member of mootools. I have something like this

```
Element.prototype.currentChild = this.getFirst();
Element.prototype.scrollToNext = function(delta, tag){ .... }
```

After that I create a new element and bind the mousewheel event to a span and acces it's currentChild.

```
body_container = new Element('div', {
events:{
            'mousewheel': function(e){
                var elem = new Element(this);
                elem.currentChild.setStyle('background-color', 'transparent');
                elem.scrollToNext(e.wheel);
                elem.currentChild.setStyle('background-color', '#C6E2FF');
                e.stop();
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'getFirst'

Do you know what might cause this?

LE: Yes, I was expecting 'this' to be an Element. But I can't see why it would be Window type.

Comment: what are you expecting `this` to be in here: *`Element.prototype.currentChild = this.getFirst();`*

Comment: Well, it is apparently a `Window` object and not an `Element` as might be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Implement to change the prototype. and you will need a function, can't say `something.prototype.method = this.somethingsMethod` as this is not bound outside of the execution context of the method.

```
Element.implement({
    currentChild: function() {
        return this.getFirst();
    },
    scrollToNext: function() {}
});
```

MooTools also has alias.

```
Element.alias('currentChild', 'getFirst');
```

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Core/Core.js#L223-225 - aliasing on type methods, when you don't want to re-implement.

to be honest, why can't you just use element storage instead?

```
'mousewheel': function(e) {
    var elem = document.id(this),
        first = elem.retrieve('currentChild');

    first || elem.store('currentChild', first = elem.getFirst());

    first.setStyle('background-color', 'transparent');
    elem.scrollToNext(e.wheel);
    first.setStyle('background-color', '#C6E2FF');
    e.stop();
}
```

Comment: I used this method but I want the currentChild to actually be a variable not a function. The declaration                                  currentChild: this.getFirst(); is just an initialization. After that it updates.

Comment: It's not intended to be static.

Comment: how would you keep it updated?? you can use `__defineGetter__` on the proto but there is no polyfill for browsers that don't support it - http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/YZcuY/ - so fallback for likes if ie6/7 will be a function.

Comment: see https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js for a proper shim that will do a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick answers. Meanwhile i found a method based on Dimitar first solution with implement. It looks like this:

```
Element.implement({ 
    currentChild: function(){ 
        if(!this._currentChild) this._currentChild = this.getFirst(); 
        return this._currentChild; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: this will be slower than `.store` / `.retrieve`, especially in IE.